# How to Upload file in particular column field of lists in shared documents using sharepoint?

Tags: list, custom-list

I am currently unable to load the file in shared documents having Level1:Daily Monitoring and inside Level1. I have one more column as Level2:Health Reports. How do I place it progamatically using C#?

I am getting the following error, while running the below code:

> "value does  not fall in expected range"

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://share.kcc.com/sites/B601"))
                        {

                            Web web = clientContext.Web;
                            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");


                            // var list = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url);
                            //Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(foldername);

                            FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                            foreach (string txtName in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\HealthcheckCAS\\CASReportquery\\Outputfiles", "*.csv"))
                            {
                                if (FileName == txtName)
                                {
                                    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtName);
                                    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
                                    fileCreationInformation.Content = file;
                                    fileCreationInformation.Url = @"http://share.kcc.com/sites/B601/Shared%20Documents/" + Path.GetFileName(txtName);
                                   // fileCreationInformation.Url = @" http://share.kcc.com/sites/B601/Shared%20Documents/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={E425027E-1CC5-4C7D-BE3A-AB46A532A185}&ID=40&RootFolder=*/" + Path.GetFileName(txtName);
                                    //list.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile=list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                                    clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                    SP.List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
                                    clientContext.Load(docList);
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                                    clientContext.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Level 2"));
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                    clientContext.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Level 1"));
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                    var Application = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Level 1").InternalName;
                                    var name = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Level 2").InternalName;
                                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[Application] = "Daily Monitoring";
                                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[name] = "Healthcheck Reports";
                                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                                    clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi @sreevani, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)